# Is there a function like the php function key() in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, object, key

I transferred a multidimensional array into JavaScript via `<?php echo json_encode($my_array); ?>` And I would like to compare entries of that JSON with other variables. So how could I get an object as string without the sub-entries?

Let's say my object is `[Object { 1429={Object { 8766={...}, 8483={...}, 7345={...}}}}, Object { 9041={...}}]`

So how could I get 1429 or 8766 as String? I know how to do that with a multidimensional array in PHP (there it is key()) - but what would it be in JavaScript?

Comment: In PHP the key() function simply returns the key of the array element that's currently being pointed to by the internal pointer. There is no internal pointer in the js object. What do you expect the key function to do?

Comment: JavaScript does not have the concept of "array pointer" (and I seldom use it in PHP). But I can't figure out what your object/array looks like (posting fake JSON doesn't help) and what rules make you choose between `1429` and `8766`. Can you please post some real code?

Comment: If you want to get at the key while *iterating through an object* then yes that can be done with JS/jQuery. Post your loop and we can assist.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP the key() function simply returns the key of the array element that's currently being pointed to by the internal pointer.

for example (from manual):

```
<?php
 $array = array(
'fruit1' => 'apple',
'fruit2' => 'orange',
'fruit3' => 'grape',
'fruit4' => 'apple',
'fruit5' => 'apple');

// this cycle echoes all associative array
 // key where value equals "apple"
while ($fruit_name = current($array)) {
if ($fruit_name == 'apple') {
    echo key($array).'<br />';
}
next($array);
}
?>
```

There is no such thing in the js like internal pointer in object, so there is no similar function.

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you! Then I'll have to find another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just an example of what I think you want. You can extend on this more.

```
var obj = {
    "5": "some",
    "8": "thing"
};
var keys = $.map(obj, function (value, key) {
    return key;
});
//result keys: ["5", "8"]
```

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bu38z/)*** - open the console to see the result.

Comment: Thank you! My json is not well formatted - so in my case it returns just [0, 1] because i need it for the highest level in my array, not the lowest.